# Search Results WebPart

Tags: web-part, search

Good Morning;

Is there anyway of increasing the width of the Search results webpart? It seems fixed at around 400px.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you are using SharePoint 2013 or 2016. The width of the items in the Search Results WebPart is defined in a CSS file.

For SharePoint 2013, the width for the CSS class `ms-srch-item` that the items use is defined in the file `searchv15.css`, located at `<SiteCollection>/_layouts/<OfficeVersion>/<LCID>/styles/Themable/searchv15.css` (OfficeVersion is **15** for SP2013, LCID would be **1033** for EN-US).

[image]

You could overwrite the width using a CSS rule in a Script Editor or Content Editor WebPart placed under the Search Results WebPart. But you have to take care of the space that the hover panel uses, which is the popup when moving the mouse over a result, and which is typically located on the right side of the result. The following CSS snippet would make the results use the available space:

```html
<style type="text/css">
.ms-srch-item {
    width: auto;
}
</style>
```